# Flutter The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()

Tags: flutter

### Down in the return Answer( answerQuestion , answer);The area where it said answerQuestion is giving me an error and code not working. can anyone help me with this.

```
import 'dart:ffi';
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'answer.dart';
import 'question.dart';

class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, Object>> questions;
  final int questionIndex;
  final Function answerQuestion;

  Quiz(
      {required this.questions,
      required this.answerQuestion,
      required this.questionIndex});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Question(questions[questionIndex]['questionText'] as String),
        ...(questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<String>).map((answer) {
          return Answer( answerQuestion , answer);
        }).toList()
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This may help you ask a better question and get a good answer https://medium.com/@gazialankus/making-sense-of-exceptions-in-flutter-and-using-them-to-ask-good-stackoverflow-questions-bff24a834a52

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
 final Function answerQuestion
```

add

```
final VoidCallback answerQuestion
```